# Make name from 2 dropdown values(Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 2 dropdown values and input fields, where I need to push a name, which contains those 2 dropdowns values.

Here is the html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>{{l("RoomType")}}</label>
  <p-dropdown [disabled]="!roomTypes.length" [options]="roomTypes" autoWidth="false" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"
    name="roomTypes" [autoWidth]="true" [(ngModel)]="room.roomTypeId"></p-dropdown>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>{{l("RoomNumber")}}</label>
  <p-dropdown [disabled]="!roomNumber.length" [options]="roomNumber" autoWidth="false" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"
    name="roomTypes" [autoWidth]="true" [(ngModel)]="room.roomNumber"></p-dropdown>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>{{l("RoomName")}}</label>
  <input #roomNameInput="ngModel" class="form-control" type="text" name="roomName" [(ngModel)]="room.roomName"
    maxlength="32">
</div>
```

I need to get the value from `RoomType` and `RoomNumber` and push them to `RoomName` when I select the fields, so the value of `RoomName` will be generated from those two values.

How I can do this?

Comment: What have you tried up to know? Can you please share any Typescript code you are using for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can call an ngModelChangeto concat the values. Follow the below code.

Your HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>{{l("RoomType")}}</label>
  <p-dropdown [disabled]="!roomTypes.length" [options]="roomTypes" autoWidth="false" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"
    name="roomTypes" [autoWidth]="true" [(ngModel)]="room.roomTypeId" (ngModelChange)="setRoomName(room.roomTypeId,room.roomNumber)"></p-dropdown>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>{{l("RoomNumber")}}</label>
  <p-dropdown [disabled]="!roomNumber.length" [options]="roomNumber" autoWidth="false" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"
    name="roomTypes" [autoWidth]="true" [(ngModel)]="room.roomNumber" (ngModelChange)="setRoomName(room.roomTypeId,room.roomNumber)"></p-dropdown>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>{{l("RoomName")}}</label>
  <input #roomNameInput="ngModel" class="form-control" type="text" name="roomName" [(ngModel)]="room.roomName"
    maxlength="32">
</div>
```

ts file

```
setRoomName(id,number){
 this.roomName=id + ' ' + number;
}
```

Addedd a space between the id and number!

Comment: It not works 
I have 

6 3 

in Room Name, but need to have labels

Comment: Try sending the labels in the ngModelChange function instead of id and number. I was assuming you were displaying the value in ngModel.

Comment: can you show the JSON for roomTypes and roomNumber. Can edit the code based on that.